# Is there any existing swing component available to do this?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox, jlist

I am looking to achieve something like this, represented in the image:

[image]

Basically it's a list, but with two columns. The first column's rows are just labels or textfields, and the second column is filled with JComboBox.
Is there already something like this built in to java?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, see [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), in particular the section on [Using a Combo Box as an Editor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox)

Comment: Wow I didn't how about this, didn't made a good search I guess!
Thanks alot mate!

Answer (score -1):

I would make a generic object that you could use to store 2 object instances or 2 new ArrayLists of any kind.

```
public class DoubleList<T1,T2>
{
    final public ArrayList<T1> listOne = new ArrayList<T1>();
    final public ArrayList<T2> listTwo = new ArrayList<T2>();
}
```

With this class, you can easily make use of it as follows:

```
DoubleList<Label, ComboBox> myCustomList = new DoubleList<Label, ComboBox>();

//Ready to use the lists by
//myCustomList.listOne  and myCustomList.listTwo
```

- And not only that, but you can now use that class for any kind of Object type xD

The other alternative is:

```
  public class DoubleObjects<T1,T2>
    {
        final public T1 one = new T1();
        final public T2 two = new T2();
    }
```

and use:

```
ArrayList<DoubleObjects<Label, ComboBox>> arrayList = new ArrayList<DoubleObjects<Label, ComboBox>>();
```

Comment: I am not sure this answer makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rockster, this is just about the control, and I know about this, thanks anyway! I was just talking about the interface itself :)   thanks for your effort anyways!